# Is it right to check session using ajax and redirect page?

Tags: ajax, security, validation, session

I am planning to validate session for secure content using ajax. This will prevent access to secure page after logout or using browser cache.

Is this right approach to implement java script in html body tag to validate the session for every page load?

I tried with $( document ).ready(). But the browser cache retains the old value which says session alive.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to assign the session value to a method inside your controller. Then when you require the session value, call the method.

Comment: How google/facebook is restricting page history of secure data? Are they not caching those pages?